# Getting the the last items in a Meteor Collection

Tags: meteor

I've got a Threads collection and I'd like to get the last post in each thread and publish those.

Anyone know the right query to do this?

I tried to do something like this, but it did not work. since the return value isn't a cursor.

```
var messages = Messages.find({ threadId: { $in: threadIds }});
// We found the messages. Now retrieve the last ones per thread.
return _.map(threadIds, function(threadId) {
  console.log('Get %s', threadId);
  Messages.find({ threadId: threadId }, {
    limit: 1, sort: { createdAt: -1 }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solution is working for me.

I do have one gripe, which is that I'm not sure if the method will run if a new message is added to a thread.

```
var messages = Messages.find({ threadId: { $in: threadIds }});

    // We found the messages. Now retrieve the last ones per thread.
    var messageCursors = [];
    _.each(threadIds, function(threadId) {
      var lastMessage = Messages.find({ threadId: threadId }, {
        sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: 1
      });
      messageCursors.push(lastMessage);
    });

    return messageCursors;
```